# SAS function that will only use non-missing values for a variable?

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a new variable that is the sum of other variables.  Should be simple enough, however if one of the variables that is being used in the calculation of the new variable has a missing value, then the new variable has a missing value as well, when I want it to just sum across the remaining non-missing variables.  For example, the data may look like:

```
a b c d e
1 . 3 2 6
```

The new variable is calculated as

```
newvar=a+b+c+d+e
```

For the above row, SAS returns a missing value for newvar because b is missing, when I would like it to return

```
newvar=a+c+d+e
```

as the answer.  Is there a simple way to get SAS to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure thing: just use the `SUM` function:

```
data _null_;
  a=1;
  b=.;
  c=3;
  d=2;
  e=6;
  newvar = sum(a,b,c,d,e);
  put newvar=;
run;
```

Comment: If you add a 0 to the sum var list you won't get a missing value, in case all vars are missing.

Comment: Another syntax trick: if your variables all start with the same thing, you can write: `newvar = sum(of var_:);` which would sum var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4 ... etc (any variable starting with var_).